# Preventing op-amp output fluctuation at power-off event

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, transient

What methods exist to place the outputs of an op-amp in a fixed state when power is removed? I have a circuit that uses an LM324 to process an analog input signal. As shown below, the input signal changes state about 4 ms after the power-off event, but the op-amp is still responsive despite the decaying supply voltage (it's powered from a 12 V rail and will operate down to about 3 V). I'd like to eliminate this output blip but I'm not sure how to do it.

I've considered using a supervisor to monitor the supply line and shut off the op-amp after the voltage drops below a certain threshold, say 8 V, which would occur before the input signal begins to decay. However, adding another IC seems like a drastic measure when I'm thinking this could be solved with some sort of RC delay circuit. Is there a simpler way?

[image]

**EDIT:** Here is my schematic. It's based off an answer to [one of my earlier questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/405805/converting-0-5-volts-linear-to-2-5-0-2-5-volts-vee). \$V_{ref}\$ is 5 V and \$V_{cc}\$ is 12 V. The circuit converts a 0-5 V input signal (\$V_{in}\$) from an [APEM HF Series joystick](https://www.apem.com/us/hf-series-42.html) to a 5-0-5 V "vee" shape. At power off, the joystick output decays down to 0 V, which results in the op-amp circuit trying to hit the 5 V rail.

[image]

**EDIT #2:** Schematic of the logic that's fed by the op-amps:

[image]

Comment: We'll probably need to see your actual circuit to understand why you got that behavior and how you might prevent it.

Comment: Did you want to use an analog switch gated by >3V threshold inside the feedback loop but with some 10k  to 0V.

Comment: This is on the verge of being closed.  Post your circuit.

Comment: @ThePhoton I've updated my question to include the schematic.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I'm not sure I follow your comment. Can you clarify it a bit? To gate the output, I was considering using an analog switch (e.g., 4066).

Comment: What is the load (what is connected to Vout)?

Comment: Yes 4066 but chose a wise threshold

Comment: @ThePhoton Vout goes to a few comparators and then some downstream 7400 logic. I'll add that schematic to my original question. There's also a V/F converter, but that's probably not relevant to the problem because I've traced the "blip" back to the very beginning with the op-amp network.

Comment: Are you intentionally omitting the bypass caps in these schematics?

Comment: @laptop2d Yes, they're omitted for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

After power off behavior is not guaranteed, you can't predict what will happen. The thing that is most concerning is the jump happens when the rail voltage is lowest.

A few things that might solve the problem:

- Use a different op amp than the LM324 which is old
- Use an op amp with an enable/disable pin
- Clamp the output on power off with a mosfet pulldown (that won't burn out the output of the op amp).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. If using a MOSFET, would this be configured so the transistor shuts off and clamps the output after the power-off event, but before the input signal changes state? In other words, the gate threshold would be between ~3 to 8 V, which I think is what SunnyskyguyEE75 was suggesting in his comment above.